# How to reference HTML React component classes without "executing" them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently whenever we want to render or pass around HTML React components, i.e, div, a, p, li, we write them in JSX syntax:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

But how would we reference one of these components without "using" them per say? What I mean is for example, for custom components, they can be imported, referenced, and passed around as `MyCustomComponent`. When we eventually want to use them, we then "execute" them via JSX syntax.

```
<MyCustomComponent someProp="">
...
</MyCustomComponent>
```

How would we go about referencing a `div` component without "using" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML in React are referenced as strings, see https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgBA9AfEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

So you can do something like

```
const Container = custom ? CustomContainer : “div”

return <Container />
```

Btw; because of this behavior, your custom components have to start with an uppercase letter since React interprets lowercase stuff as HTML elements when used in JSX

Answer (score 0):

JSX is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`. In case it's lower-cased, a string is used as React element type, otherwise provided variable is used as element type.

It can be wrapper component:

```
const MyCustomComponent = props => <div {...props}/>;
<MyCustomComponent/> // React.createElement(MyCustomComponent)
```

Or a string:

```
const MyCustomComponent = 'div';
<MyCustomComponent/> // React.createElement(MyCustomComponent)
```